# CSS transition image

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is the background image:

[image: The background image]

```css
#logo
{background-image:url('logo.png');width:20px;height:23px;}
#logo:hover
{background-position:0 -23px;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;}
#logo span
{margin-left:-3000px;}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div id="logo"><span>logo</span></div></a>
```

This code gives me a slide effect (a vertical slide from the black S to the pink one) instead of the fade effect I'm looking for. Creating two images, would solve the issue, but that is not possible in this case.

**How do I get the fade affect when using only one single image?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/Wds5z/4/

```
a, #logo {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ZnN.png') 0 -23px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 23px;
    display: block;
}

#logo {
    background-position: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
       -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
            transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

#logo:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#logo span {
    margin-left:-3000px;
}​
```

Comment: @Neil you work in FF :) probably it's a good idea to add all the prefixes to widen browser support.. updated

Comment: Zoltan, your code works great. But there is no fade when you mouse off. Is that posible to add?